# Adding vertical space between lines

Tags: tables

I would like to obtain some more space between the chemical symbol "Nb" and the horizontal line from the cell above. Using `\stretcharray` command has helped a little to add this spce but increasing the number too much would result in a too big table the same holds true for "Nb2O5" and for all other chemical symbols. Is there a method to add this space, in a more apt way?

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{setspace}
    \begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding of table cells

    \newcommand*{\myparbox}[2][12mm]{\parbox{#1}{{\footnotesize  \bfseries #2}}}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \setstretch{0.85}
        \caption{Input parameters used for the GA optimizer.}
        \footnotesize% IMS: need this to get the 9pt text size in table cells % TODO is correct ?
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|}
            \hline
            & {\myparbox[10mm]{Material}} & {\myparbox{Property}} & {\myparbox{Value}} \\
            \hline

            \parbox[t]{2mm}{ \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c {90}{Scenario 1}}} & Nb & $m_r$ & 1 \\
                &                                       & $\Psi$ & $4.33 \ eV$ \\
                & NbN                                   & $m_r$  & $1$\\
                &                                       & $\Psi$ & $4.7 \ eV$  \\
                \cline{2-4}
                & Nb\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{5} & $m_r$  & $1$\\
                &                                       & $\chi$ & $4.23 \ eV$ \\
                &                                       & $K$    & $25$ \\
            \hline
            \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Scenario 2}}} & Al & $m_r$ & 1 \\
                &   & $\Psi$ & $5 \ eV$ \\
                \cline{2-4}
                & Nb\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{5} & $m_r$  & 1\\
                &                                       & $\chi$ & $4.44 \ eV$ \\
                &                                       & $K$    & 25 \\
                & Al\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3} & $m_r$  & 1\\
                &                                       & $\chi$ & $2.32 \ eV$ \\
                &                                       & $K$    & 9.7 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab_inputpar}
        %\vspace{-\baselineskip}% remove one line of space below this table
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Apologies in advance for any unneccessary packages becasuse I cleaned the unneccessary packages rapidly before posting. Many thanks in advnace.

Comment: No apologies :-) we are here to help you.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of errors.

Comment: OT: you should use a dedicated package  like `mhchem` for typesetting chemical formula, Ditto for your units with `siunitx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would redesign your table as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Input parameters used for the GA optimizer.}
    \label{tab_inputpar}
\centering
%\footnotesize% IMS: need this to get the 9pt text size in table cells % TODO is correct ?
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}% for the vertical padding of table cells
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Scenario 2}
\begin{tabular}{l c >{$}c<{$} l }
    \toprule
        & \thead{Material}   & \text{\thead{Property}}  & \thead{Value}   \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{7}{*}{\rotcell{Scenario 1}}
        & \ce{Nb}       & m_r     & 1 \\
        &               & \Psi    & \SI{4.33}{eV}   \\
    \addlinespace
        & \ce{NbN}      & m_r     & 1\\
        &               & \Psi    & \SI{4.7}{eV}    \\
    \addlinespace
        & \ce{Nb2O5}    & m_r     & 1\\
        &               & \chi    & \SI{4.23}{eV}   \\
        &               & K       & 25              \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{8}{*}{\rotcell{Scenario 2}}
        & Al            & m_r     & 1               \\
        &               & \Psi    & \SI{5}{ eV}     \\
    \addlinespace
        &\ce{Nb2O5}     & m_r     & 1\\
        &               & \chi    &  \SI{4.44}{eV}  \\
        &               & K       & 25              \\
    \addlinespace
        & \ce{Al2O3}    & m_r     & 1               \\
        &               & \chi    &  \SI{2.32}{eV}  \\
        &               & K       & 9.7             \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

in code are consider all comment below your question.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this simpler code, based on `makecell` for the cells padding and formatting, `siunitx` and `chemformula`:

```
 \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{siunitx, chemformula}
 \usepackage{float, multirow, rotating, caption, makecell}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\myparbox}[2][12mm]{\parbox{#1}{{\footnotesize \bfseries #2}}}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Input parameters used for the GA optimizer.}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}\makegapedcells
    \footnotesize% IMS: need this to get the 9pt text size in table cells % TODO is correct ?
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|}
        \hline
        & \thead{Material} & \thead{Property} & \thead{Value} \\
        \hline

        \parbox[t]{2mm}{ \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Scenario 1}}} & \ch{Nb} & $m_r$ & 1 \\
            & & $\Psi$ & \SI{4.33}{\eV} \\
            & \ch{NbN} & $m_r$ & \Gape[1ex][0pt]{1}% \bigstrut[t]
            \\
            & & $\Psi$ & \SI{4.7}{\eV} \\
            \cline{2-4}
            &\ch{Nb2O5} & $m_r$ & $1$\\
            & & $\chi$ & \SI{4.23}{\ eV} \\
            & & $K$ & $25$ \\
        \hline
        \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Scenario 2}}} & Al & $m_r$ & 1 \\
            & & $\Psi$ & \SI{5}{\eV} \\
            \cline{2-4}
            & \ch{Nb2 O5} & $m_r$ & 1\\
            & & $\chi$ & \SI{4.44}{\eV} \\
            & & $K$ & 25 \\
            & \ch{Al2 O3} & $m_r$ & \Gape[1ex][0pt]{1}\\
            & & $\chi$ & \SI{2.32}{\eV} \\
            & & $K$ & 9.7 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab_inputpar}
    %\vspace{-\baselineskip}% remove one line of space below this table
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really wonderful solutions! @Bernard You solve the issue and keep to the regulations set by the organizing community. Zarko's Really impressive solution. Although both solutions work for me, and I am puzzled whose answer shall I accept. However, I will go for that of Zarko although I am not sure they will accept it the way it is as it has slightly different technique.

Comment: @Mazen: Zarko's solution with  `booktabs`  is really nice– and I would have proposed a similar solution, but decided to stick to  vertical rules since you used them, and the resulting table, while looking not so professional, isn't really ugly.